# How to select options in dropdown when no value provided?

Tags: javascript

I have a specific issue here. I'm trying to create an extension to help populate some fields in an already built web app.

One of the sections is a drop down where I will select the month, but for some reason I cannot get it to work for the life of me. Here is the HTML for it.

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.monthOfYearOptions, optionsText: 'description', optionsCaption: ' ', value: rangeBeginMonthSelection, enable: holidayDateType() == 'dateRange'" class="small inline" title="" disabled="">
<option value=""> </option>
<option value="">January</option>
<option value="">February</option>
<option value="">March</option>
<option value="">April</option>
<option value="">May</option>
<option value="">June</option>
<option value="">July</option>
<option value="">August</option>
<option value="">September</option>
<option value="">October</option>
<option value="">November</option>
<option value="">December</option>
</select>
```

I've been trying stuff like

```
$('[data-bind="options: $parent.monthOfYearOptions"]').val('January')
```

But of course without a value it does nothing. I've also been trying to get it to just select the nth option in the list, but I'm still pretty new to coding so I'm struggling.

Does anyone have any creative ideas where I can write a script to get it to select whatever I put in there?

Comment: The only way I see is to add click listener on every options and select it using JS. But why aren't you able to add values ?

Comment: I'm using HTML from an already built web app that I do not have access to. Just trying to automate my job a little bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter through all of the `input`s in the `select` to find the one with a `textContent` of "January" to and then set the `selected` property of that option.

```
$('select option').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == "January";
}).prop('selected', 'selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: $parent.monthOfYearOptions, optionsText: 'description', optionsCaption: ' ', value: rangeBeginMonthSelection, enable: holidayDateType() == 'dateRange'" class="small inline" title="" disabled="">
<option value=""> </option>
<option value="">January</option>
<option value="">February</option>
<option value="">March</option>
<option value="">April</option>
<option value="">May</option>
<option value="">June</option>
<option value="">July</option>
<option value="">August</option>
<option value="">September</option>
<option value="">October</option>
<option value="">November</option>
<option value="">December</option>
</select>
<script>
$('select option').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == "January";
}).prop('selected', 'selected');
</script>
```

Comment: @Agitated_Knowledge No problem.